# are these nativecrypto error messages error messages?

Tags: android, ssl

When establishing a TLS connection between my android phone and my server I get following `nativecrypto error messages in logcat`:

```
06-30 21:55:06.565: E/NativeCrypto(24826): ssl=0x75e58650 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x75e4da40 arg=0x0
06-30 21:55:06.566: E/NativeCrypto(24826): ssl=0x75e58650 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=RSA
```

I was not able to find an explanation on google or stack for this kind of error logs and somehow I think they are not real errors, more likely informations.

Can someone elaborate what these messages mean?

I am using TLS and I have a `serverkey and truststore` as well as `clientkey- and truststore`.

Comment: It sad that no one can give an answer or comment. Can not believe that no one knows what these messages mean..... really sad...

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326358/is-this-android-ssl-pinning-implementation-correct-and-why-is-this-error-showing

Answer (score 0):

well this errors occur but it occur if one have used invalid or incorrect code
it has occurred in my code but i did not properly initialized Context object.

Comment: Can you share your context initialization? I know that there has to be a code/or a keystore truststore problem..but the question is how to configure the context correctly...

Comment: i got the error while i was using google maps and in that i am sharing code for the fragment where i made mistake in context I am pasting correct version hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue from your application this issue is your device, it also appear in my app, Dont worry with SSL on android it is normal log.