# Android - Security with HTTPS and SSL - Unknown certificate authority - NativeCrypto Exception

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

Following this one:
https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/articles/security-ssl.html part:Unknown certificate authority - example of University of Washington.

Now I can access and communicate with the server. I got the response from the server as expecting. However, there are some error on Android log:

```
E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x61ede338 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x618358c0 arg=0x0
E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x61ede338 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=RSA
```

I don't have any ideas where this comes from? Is this normal?
Someone can explain/help me out please?

Comment: I am observing this same problem when connecting to a remote server having a perfectly valid certificate (according to this certificate checker, https://www.digicert.com/help)

Comment: Possible duplicate of these questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326358/is-this-android-ssl-pinning-implementation-correct-and-why-is-this-error-showing
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160102/are-these-nativecrypto-error-messages-error-messages

Comment: I'am always looking for a further answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That log is normal, it issue from your device, it also appear in my app, please dont worry.
With SSL on android, you can try this lib for your work,
check it [here](https://github.com/ge0rg/MemorizingTrustManager)

Comment: Thanks you very much. Are you vietnamese? I'm new in Android. Can I have you email? I'm working with ssl - php server. It would be nice if you can help me some ^^

Comment: Yes we are VNese :). quocnhat7@gmail.com, nice to meet you here.